# python list syntax

Tags: python, list

```
def bucketsort(arr, k):
    counts = [0] * k
    for x in arr:
        counts[x] += 1
    sorted_arr = []
    for i, count in enumerate(counts):
        sorted_arr.extend([i] * count)
    return sorted_arr
```

Can someone please explain this syntax?

1)

```
  counts = [0] * k
```

2)
 `for i, count` as in

```
  for i, count in enumerate(counts):
        sorted_arr.extend([i] * count)
```

In python there are only list and dictionaries? no array\queues\stack ?

Comment: 1. Creates an array called counts, with k elements, all equal to 0. For things like these, just use the shell to test what happens.

Comment: `list` *is* an array (the name's pointless and confusing in my opinion, but whatever) and makes a very good stack too (it's dynamic and over-allocating, so you get amortized O(1) for appending/pushing and `pop`ing is O(1) too). Queues (as well as deques) are in the standard library. Off the top of my head, there are also sets and heaps.

Comment: @Bane which shell is recommended? I don't have python installed yet.

Comment: @EladBenda Install Python. Any Python. You can just use whatever shell your system provides. Worry about fancy shells later. Very hard to learn a language without being able to execute code.

Comment: Don't forget to check on the available container types in the `collections` module, esp. `Counter` seems to fit your program.

Comment: @delnan List is not an array. It is an array-backed vector.

Comment: @Marcin That depends very much on the definition of "array" and "vector". In C/C++ terminology, you are right. But the term "(dynamic) array" is also in common use. Regardless of terms, `list` is: An ordered collection mapping indices from `0` to `len(my_list) - 1` whose size is not in stone but can change freely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sequence Types and multiplication

```
[0]*k
```

This means a list of size `k` containing `0`-s. This works for any sequence object, for example:

```
"foo"*2
```

## Iteration over a list

Consider the following syntax:

```
for i, value in enumerate(values):
    pass
```

This exploits two properties of Python. The first is the `for` syntax, which works like `foreach` in some other languages. For example, the following will loop 3 times, with `i` being equal `0` the first time, `1` the second, and `2` the third:

```
for i in [0,1,2]:
    pass
```

The second is value unpacking. Given a sequence type, you can unpack its values into different variables:

```
i, j = (42, 69, )
```

After you run this line `i` will hold `42`, and `j` will hold `69`. That's a tuple, by the way, which is an immutable (i.e. you can't change it) sequence.

Lastly, the function `enumerate` takes a sequence and returns a sequence of tuples where the first element is an index number, and the second element is the value of the sequence at that index. Well, to be precise it takes an sequencable object and returns an iterator, but same difference.

So, basically, by using that syntax you get both the index and the value. Nice.

## Built-in sequence types in Python

You have a list (`[1, "fish", 2, "fish", "red", "fish", "blue", "fish"]`), a dict (`{'one': 2, 2: 'three'}`), a tuple (`(one, [1,2], three, )`), and a set (`{"one", 3, (1,2)}`, Python 2.7 syntax). You also have a frozenset which is an immutable set and has no syntactic sugar.

See the [Python documentation for built-in types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

Then there are some more container types in the standard [`collections` package](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html). And some more [data types in other places in the standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/datatypes.html).

Also, you can use the standard list as a stack or a queue. And don't let the `array` package fool you - you don't use it in order to implement arrays (you use plain lists for that), you use it to import binary data. It's a sort of companion for the `struct` package.

Comment: P.S. This is an excellent textbook for Python 3: [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist, 3rd Edition](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/). The 2nd edition (available at the same site) discusses Python 2. And just get the standard python off of [python.org](http://python.org) and notepad++ or something to edit text with.

Answer (score 3):

```
[0] * k
```

evaluates to a list containing `k` elements, each element being `0`.

```
[i] * count
```

evaluates to a list containing `count` elements, each element being `i`.

The relevant section of documentation is here: [Sequence Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

```
for i, count in enumerate(counts):
```

---

The [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) function returns an iterator that yields tuples. Each tuple contains an index and the associated item from `counts`.  So your code is equivalent to:

```
i = 0
for count in counts:
    #do something with i and count
    i += 1
```

Comment: @EladBenda If you don't know anything about Python, and hence have to ask about basically every construct, you're better off diving into the documentation, a book, or at least a tutorial before asking here. It may very well be quicker and doesn't come off as lazy.

Comment: @EladBenda I've added coverage of that now. But I agree with delnan's comments. You need a working installation of Python and a good introductory text book.

Answer (score 0):

Python has classes for [arrays](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html), [queues](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) and much more (apart from good and googleable docs). You can also use lists as [queues](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-queues) and [stacks](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks).